# view behaviour with Datediff

Tags: sql-server

any idea why when i use this code

```
SELECT * FROM Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory WHERE TagName = 'LT73011.Out_PV' 
AND datediff(HOUR, DateTime, '2018-03-14 08:02:23.449') = 0
```

knowing that Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory is my view 
i get blank

but when i query with this

```
SELECT * FROM Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory WHERE TagName = 'LT73011.Out_PV' 
AND DateTime <= '2018-03-14 08:59:00.000'
```

i get all the values that happened at the hour 8am

is there's a curtain restriction with a view? how can i work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your observations/behavior, but if you want an exact way to target 8am on a certain date then try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory
WHERE
    TagName = 'LT73011.Out_PV' AND
    DateTime >= '2018-03-14 08:00:00' AND DateTime < '2018-03-14 09:00:00';
```

This approach also has the added advantage that an index on the `DateTime` column can be used (i.e. the `WHERE` clause is sargable).